# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Array' to 'decimal[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#

How to convert this in C# code?

```
//Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Array' to 'decimal[]'.
//An explicit conversion exists
Array[] s = new Array[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    s[i] = average; //average is decimal [] 
}
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Mean = s[i]; //mean is decimal[] & s[i] system array 
}
```

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting this code as a comment.

Comment: @deepakdwivedi Callum and I have edited your post with this code. Stop posting your code in the comments.

Comment: @deepakdwivedi if you look at your question you should see some small hyperlinks that says `share edit close delete flag` clicking edit lets you change the text of your question

Comment: Pls add information about what you are trying to achieve because the invalid cast is just a result of a wrong approach.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to setup a jagged array. In which case, I suspect the best option is to type `s` as `decimal[][]`:

```
decimal[][] s = new decimal[10][];
```

Then everything will *just work*.

You can also *cast*:

```
Mean = (decimal[])s[i];
```

but that is less satisfying, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you are trying to do with this code, as it does not calculate an average or mean,

but you are using the typeless array class, this is primarily intended to serve as a common base class so that all arrays exhibit the same behaviour, it can also be used in some rare situations when you don't know what type the array is

the correct way to defined an array is TypeName[ArraySize] so if you want a decimal array of size 10 then the correct use would be `decimal[10]`

here is your "working" code:

```
decimal demo_average = 0;
decimal demo_mean = 0;

decimal[] s = new decimal[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    s[i] = demo_average;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    demo_mean = s[i]; 
}
```

Comment: an explanation telling the OP why he went wrong would improve this

Comment: how? I've not a clue what OP is trying to do because he/she obviously likes mysterious questions ^^

Comment: they've clearly just moved to c# and are using trying to use arrays but have mistaken the type-less arrays as how to create an array and not the Typed arrays that are the correct route